# Image filling in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of a box like below (on left) and after writing the following python code i get the image on the right

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_file = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/box.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cv2.imshow('Image', closing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

I want to remove the noise (or fill the image) such that box part in the image fills completely black and other black dots below (other than box) are removed. I have tried various morphological transformation functions but did not get required results. Any suggestions of functions that can do it for me in Opencv

Comment: Did you try a [gaussian blur](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) of the image or [dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY` -- that's wrong, the image you loaded is BGR (the default OpenCV arrangement). According to [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) the conversion to gray uses different weights per channel, hence `RGB2GRAY` and `BGR2GRAY` are **not** equivalent.

Comment: Some notes: avoid lossy compression (like JPG), it adds artifacts which hinder analysis. Also, rather than discarding to color info by going to just grayscale, maybe try HSV, and combine results from several planes together. | Planes: [H](http://imgur.com/6PE6zX2) [S](http://imgur.com/shs2Tjy) [V](http://imgur.com/EE7R7SL) | Thresholded: [H](http://imgur.com/wBzBlxs) [S](http://imgur.com/n43o2WI) [V](http://imgur.com/e84Evpn) | [This script](http://pastebin.com/Uk4fn3qR) gets me this [result](http://imgur.com/8275zDV). Maybe you can refine that further :)